# Google Maps Pick a location?

Tags: html, google-maps, hyperlink

Can you design a google map, with multiple locations, and when you click on a location it opens a link to that locations page?

Answer (score 0):

The basic Google Maps page can be set up using instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Add markers in the `initialize()` function, using

```
var marker new google.mapsMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.952517,-75.19618), //your coordinates
    map: map,
    title:"Location 1",
    url: "http://www.location1.com",
});`
```

Then add links to the markers by adding an event listener to your map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = marker.url;
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xpdQ/3/) with a couple of markers. Keep in mind that the links won't open on jsfiddle but would open on a normal website.